# Not Have To Specify Middleware for each Router express

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, express-router

In Express, I'm using different routers for each of my routes, like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const postRouter = require('./postRouter');
const userRouter = require('./userRouter');
const app = express();


app.use('/posts', postRouter);
app.use('/users', userRouter);
```

And then in my router files, I have the routes.

However, let's say that on all my pages I'm using sessions. If I want to do this, I have to say `router.use(sessionMiddleware);` in each router file.

My question is is that if I can still use multiple routers without having to specify the middleware in each file. I've tried `app.use();` but that doesn't work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do what you claim doesn't work:

```
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
```

However I can guess why your attempt doesn't work. It probably comes from your misunderstanding of how Express work.

At it's core express is a middleware processing engine. You configure a list of middlewares in Express (endpoints are also middlewares, they just happen to be the last to be executed) and Express will process them one at a time in order.

The last sentence is the most important to understand: **Express will process middlewares one at a time in order**.

So if you do something like

```
app.use('/posts', postRouter);
app.use('/users', userRouter);
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
```

What you are doing is tell express to:

- First see if the request matches '/posts', if it does execute `postRouter`

  - If `postRouter` is executed see if the route call the `next()` function
    without any argument. If `next()` is called continue processing.
  - If `next()` is called with any argument **stop processing** and proceed
    to the error handler (by default this will send an error page back to
    the browser)
  - If `next()` is **not** called **stop processing**
- If processing continues, second see if the request matches '/users'
  if it does execute `userRouter`

  - If `userRouter` is executed see if the route call the `next()` function
    without any argument. If `next()` is called continue processing.
  - If `next()` is called with any argument **stop processing** and proceed
    to the error handler
  - If `next()` is **not** called **stop processing**
- If processing continues execute `sessionMiddleware`

So if your flow (yes, it's a program flow, not simply API calls to Express) is like the above this means the `sessionMiddleware` will not get executed for the `/posts` and `/users` routes.

This means you need to change your program flow as follows:

```
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
app.use('/posts', postRouter);
app.use('/users', userRouter);
```

As you can see, Express is very flexible. Say for example you want `/posts` to use your session middleware but not `/users`. You can do this instead:

```
app.use('/users', userRouter);
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
app.use('/posts', postRouter);
```